Quadratic factorization box method ambiguous in some cases?
Factorizing $5x^2 − 31x + 6$ using box method we get this box:

Row 1: GCF of $5x^2$ and $-x = x$
Row 2: GCF of $-30x$ and $6 = 6 (not -6)$
Col 1: GCF of $5x^2$ and $-30x = 5x$
Col 2: GCF of $-x$ and $6$ is $1 (not -1)$
Hence we get $(x + 6)(5x + 1)$, which is the wrong answer.
The right answer is $(x - 6)(5x -1)$.
So in some cases the box method doesn't work?
